# Linkage error for one function only. Other functions with similar signature in same class and CPP file are working fine

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, dllexport, lnk2019

The similar question for this type of linkage error has been asked before, and I have looked into most (if not all) of them.
Some similar questions here, GitHub and MSDN that I looked into to solve this problem:

[Github:](https://github.com/nickgillian/grt/issues/133)

[MSDN:](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d94f6af3-e330-4962-a150-078da57ee5d0/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-declspecdllimport-public-thiscall?forum=vcgeneral)

[StackOverflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867030/c-dll-unresolved-external-symbol)

[StackOverflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529666/how-to-fix-visual-studio-2012-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-decls)

[Stackoverflow 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908399/unresolved-external-symbol-declspecdllimport)

[Stackoverflow 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901973/unresolved-external-symbol-declspecdllimport)

[Stackoverflow 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446887/2-x-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-errors-when-compiling?rq=1)

**Problem:** 
 I have a legacy product with over 400+ Visual Studio projects in 4 Visual Studio `Solution` Files. I am facing the problem with a project that is a COM component, it is supposed to use a `dll`(that contains static functions) created from another project; all the static function from the `dll` are working fine, except one, that I am trying to add in it.
The project that creates the `dll` is building fine without any error, the `header` file and `cpp` file that contain static functions are as follows.

file: **`InvocationInterface.h`**

```
using namespace some_namespace;

#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma pack(8)
#else
#pragma pack(1) // tag for search
#endif

typedef struct 
{

    long nDBMS;
    long nDBMSVersion;
    long nDBMSMinorVersion;
    LPSTR szCaption; 
    LPSTR szRepGroupName;
    std::vector<bool> xDBMSOptions;
    EouGdmIdList selectedEntityIds;
    BOOL bIsAlterScript;
    int nInvoke;
    LPSTR szConnectionInfo;
    LPSTR szPassword;
    LPSTR szOptionXML;
    LPSTR szDDLPath;
} EouFEPARAM;

class EOU_EXPORT CUIInvocationInterface
{ 
public:
    CUIInvocationInterface(void);
    ~CUIInvocationInterface(void);

    // A lot of other similar static functions
    static void SetIncludeSysTablesForRevEng(GDMModelSetI* pxModelSet,BOOL bShow);

    static void setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI* pxModelSet, CString csPath, bool append);

};
#pragma pack( pop, EouUIInvocationInterface_H_pack )
```

The **`InvocationInterface.cpp`** file:

```
#include "Header_files"

//Constructor
CUIInvocationInterface::CUIInvocationInterface(void)
{
}
//Destructor
CUIInvocationInterface::~CUIInvocationInterface(void)
{
}

// Old legacy code working just fine if I remove the function that is casusing linking error
void SetIncludeSysTablesForRevEng(GDMModelSetI* pxModelSet, BOOL bShow)
{
    return SetIncludeSysTables(pxModelSet, bShow);
}

// Function that is causing Linking Error
void setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI* pModelSet, CString & sFilePath, bool bAppend)
{
    CWnd * wnd = nullptr;
    EouRESetOptions ForRE(wnd);
    ForRE.ProcessCSV(sFilePath, true);
}
```

The `COM` componenet that is using these functions are using them in following way:
**ComProxyFile.cpp**

```
bool function(formal_parameters, ...)
{


    ...
    ...

    CUIInvocationInterface::setNSMCSV(pxModelSet, strCSVpath, true);
    CUIInvocationInterface::SetIncludeSysTablesForRevEng(pxModelSet, bIncludeSystemTables);

    ...
    ...



    SOMECLASS::OnInvokeAFunction(args, ...);
    return bRet;
}
```

The function `setNSMCSV` is causing the `LNK2019` error, when I am building the COM component that is using the `dll`, there are `20+` such static functions declared and defined in a similar way but all are working fine except `setNSMCSV`, that I am trying to implement.
If I build the project that is using these functions then it gives me following error:
`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl CUIInvocationInterface::setNSMCSV(class GDMModelSetI *,class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > >,bool)"`

If I comment out the `CUIInvocationInterface::setNSMCSV(pxModelSet, strCSVpath, true);` line then it compiles just fine.

I tried giving `setNSMCSV` function definition `__declspec(dllexport) __cdecl`, `extern "C"`, and using `pragma comment`, adding `.lib` to `COM` component that is using the functions, and other things that I could find that has been suggested in other similar questions here.

Why is this single function causing this issue? Other functions have same signatures and similar implementation but those are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In InvocationInterface.cpp, you need to change your function definition to include the class name, i.e. from:

```
void setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI* pModelSet, CString & sFilePath, bool bAppend)
{
    CWnd * wnd = nullptr;
    EouRESetOptions ForRE(wnd);
    ForRE.ProcessCSV(sFilePath, true);
}
```

to:

```
void CUIInvocationInterface::setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI* pModelSet, CString & sFilePath, bool bAppend)
{
    CWnd * wnd = nullptr;
    EouRESetOptions ForRE(wnd);
    ForRE.ProcessCSV(sFilePath, true);
}
```

Comment: I had started with that. That gives me an error `error C2511: 'void CUIInvocationInterface::setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI *,CString &,bool)' : overloaded member function not found in 'CUIInvocationInterface'`

Comment: Ah, you had another issue, the definition has a reference for the second parameter, but the declaration does not have a reference. Either use `CString`for both, or use `CString&` for both.

Comment: Oh, damn!! I am so dumb. I can't believe it. Thank you for pointing it out. I guess I am going blind or something. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change `void setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI* pModelSet, CString & sFilePath, bool bAppend)` to `void CUIInvocationInterface::setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI* pModelSet, CString & sFilePath, bool bAppend)` in the `.cpp` file. You have declared it as a static class function but defined as a free function (not as a class member).

Your header:

```
class EOU_EXPORT CUIInvocationInterface
{ 
public:
    CUIInvocationInterface(void);
    ~CUIInvocationInterface(void);

    // A lot of other similar static functions
    static void SetIncludeSysTablesForRevEng(GDMModelSetI* pxModelSet,BOOL bShow);

    static void setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI* pxModelSet, CString csPath, bool append); // <-- Static class member function

};
```

Your cpp:

```
// Function that is causing Linking Error
void setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI* pModelSet, CString & sFilePath, bool bAppend) //<-- not a member function
{
    CWnd * wnd = nullptr;
    EouRESetOptions ForRE(wnd);
    ForRE.ProcessCSV(sFilePath, true);
}
```

Comment: I had actually started with that, that is giving me an error: `error C2511: 'void CUIInvocationInterface::setNSMCSV(GDMModelSetI *,CString &,bool)' : overloaded member function not found in 'CUIInvocationInterface'`